# Identify a connector type for board to board connection

Tags: connector

I cannot figure out what connector types are.
They are mating to connect a board to a board.
They look like a total of 240 positions (4 rows x 60).
I searched Digikey but I couldn't find a similar one.
I hope someone can find out.
Thank you.[image]

Comment: Please add dimensions: total length, width, and pin to pin spacing (pitch).

Comment: "Mezzanine" or "board-to-board", possibly made by JST.

Comment: From the numbers on the PCB it looks like 120 positions with each one making contact on both sides